# Response is undefined in post request (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, response

I have a route handler which calls a signup function in an authentication controller, when I go to the specified route:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post("/signup", authentication.signup());
};
```

My auth controller:

```
exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
  res.send({ success: true });
};
```

But when I start up the server, I says that it can't read property "send" of undefined. As a can't even run my server, I can't use postman to test my API routes.

Why is it trying to call send, even before I have visited the route? I am running my server using the node http library with my express app.

Comment: app.post("/signup", authentication.signup);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.post("/signup", authentication.signup());` **calls** `authentication.signup` and passes its return value into `app.post`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

Instead, just pass the function itself into `app.post`; Express will call it later in response to a POST on that route:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post("/signup", authentication.signup);
  // No () here ---------------------------^
};
```